# Patio Light Fixture To Electrical Socket

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, outdoor, socket

So we are putting up some string lights on our covered patio and want to use those instead of our patio light fixture right outside the door. I've removed the light fixture and there is an octagonal electric box. I was hoping to put an electrical socket in there and plug the string lights in through there to control with the light switch inside the house. What can I use the fit over that octagonal box and keep the socket in use and weather proof? I'm having the hardest time finding something to work. The octagonal metal box is in brick and mortar. I'd prefer to NOT remove the box and replace with a different one if possible.  The box looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice, especially as two different users ([gman](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/54783/gman) and [Gerret](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/54781/gerret)). You should look into merging the two accounts.

Comment: The first account was a guest account. Didn't want to post again, but I couldn't respond on the other one. I will merge. In the meantime, I have a question about something I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: I have officially requested the merge.  Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Is this a 3.5" or a 4" octagon box we're dealing with here?

Comment: 3.5" box, which has made it tougher to deal with.  I'm not opposed to drilling into the brick and using tapcon screws to anchor if needed

Comment: I was going to write a snappy answer, but apparently I'm going to have to spend time fiddling with a 3.5" octagon box and various wiring devices to see if *anything* fits in those infernal things!

Comment: I know only one outlet will fit in it.  I tried a 2-gang weatherproof in use cover and both sockets wouldn't fit inside.  I'm hoping there's a 1-gang weatherproof in use cover that can also cover the whole box or ALMOST the whole box.  I've got clear caulk ready to put around the outside of whatever goes there.  It will always be plugged in.

Comment: Can you get a standard duplex outlet to fit in the box?

Comment: Yes, a standard duplex outlet will fit, but it has nothing to screw into.

Comment: @GMan -- will it fit on the diagonal, between the two cover plate screws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible idea for this connection is to look for an octagon electrical box cover that looks like this:

[image]

Then acquire a box to box electrical connector that looks like this:

[image]

This can then be joined to a back hole in an appropriate electrical box that gets surface mounted to the face of the wall. This box would then accommodate the needed outlet and exterior in-use cover assembly.

Comment: Good solution. If you can't find a cover with a knockout you can make one with a hole saw or knockout kit. Also, a chase nipple will bring the box (probably a bell box) tighter to the cover than the box to box connector. 

Comment: The advantage of the box to box connector is that it can be secured to the octagon box cover before mounting the cover to the existing box. The typical chase nipple would be a bit more complicated to use unless either the nut or nipple were bonded to the box cover. I suppose the nipple could be used with two nuts but then it almost becomes almost the same as what I suggested.

Comment: Hmm yes. I was just thinking I would thread the nipple through the cover into the bell box and cover and tighten so the screws on the cover were still open, make the joints in the existing box and then attach it to the octagon box creating a flush fit.

Comment: Great ideas Michael and Archon.  I think this is the right way to go with it.  I'm leaning toward the chase nipple over the box connector to get it as flush as possible, but the idea is essentially the same.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Hold on. How do you physiclly support the box you are adding?   You can't have it dangling by the nipple, they are not listed for that.

Comment: @Harper - Never suggested that the outer box dangled from the nipple. As a matter of fact I said exactly this in my answer: "an appropriate electrical box that gets surface mounted to the face of the wall." I had to restrain from recommending any specific box because of the various types available and the fact that an external "in-use" cover may also impact selection.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. It's functioning as it should and the stringer is up. Whole new patio at night. Thanks!!!

Comment: @GMan - Glad to hear the feedback!! Were you able to get a suitable in-use enclosure to work?

Comment: Yes, of course. Used a Bell single gang box and an expandable in-use case.