# Does the switched load on a GFCI switch need to be grounded?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I'm in a similar as situation described here:
[Can a mud ring be used in reverse?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/97109/can-a-mud-ring-be-used-in-reverse)

I have an octagon box outside behind stucco. I want to plug in string patio lights. The lights have a 3 prong plug. So I'd need to use a lamp-to-outlet adapter [image: adapter]

Then a cheater [image: cheater]

This seems bad.

There's no ground conductor outside in the octogon.

I thought I'd replace the switch with a GFCI **switch** for a little extra protection.

The GFCI manual says "The load must be grounded". Is this true?
I found this [image: switch wiring] here: https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2020/04/wire-gfci-combo-switch-outlet.html#wiring-a-gfci-combo-switch-outlet-with-a-light-bulb

which seems to say I can do what I think I want, but it's a cartoon.

Is this possible and if so, is it worth doing?

Comment: That's not a GFCI switch.  That is a combo switch-outlet. You can get just a GFCI switch, it looks like a deadfront (only buttons, no sockets).  Test/Reset are Off/On.  It is rated for that service.

Comment: Regardless, what you are trying to do is a Code violation, as you are provisioning a new receptacle, and that always requires grounding (and GFCI if outdoors).  That said, I think your idea is more than safe enough.

Comment: thanks! @Harper-ReinstateMonica I didn't see the switch-only version at the local home store. 
I see them online now. If I use one of those... I'm not provisioning a new receptacle maybe?

Comment: Can you take the cover off your octagon box and measure its width please?

Comment: It's very behind stucco. The mounting holes/bolts are 2" 3/4 apart. And yes, the "cover" is currently just the cheap round indoor lamp holder mounted sideways too it... I'd rather attach an outdoor box if there was a way to do that without dealing with the stucco.

Answer (score 1):

### Change the lamp to a receptacle.

Since you are not using the lamp at all, simply tear it off the wall and store it until you no longer want a receptacle there. Now you're looking at an octagon box *that is grounded*.

Since it's the smaller and largely obsolete [3-1/2" box](https://cdn-assets.unilogcorp.com/ASSETS/DOCUMENTS/ITEMS/EN/RACO_110_Specification_Sheet.pdf), you'll need to mount an extension box that steps up to either the more common [4" octagon box](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/electrical-box-dimensions.413777/post-3422009), or a 4x4" square box.  An electrical supply house will have the shop knowledge to know exactly what you want; box stores tend to be a disaster for "less popular" stuff like this.

Once you have a box capable of accepting a receptacle, then install one, along with an outdoor in-use cover, such as a Taymac MM410CA for 4" octagon boxes.

"That was easy"

Since it is an outdoor receptacle, it needs GFCI protection. **NOW, apply your idea** to use either a GFCI switch (deadfront with switch rating), or the GFCI switch/receptacle combo device you proposed, as you prefer.

Comment: I tried a Taymac MM410CA first. It doesn't fit. If there's some kind of adapter I can use without breaking away the stucco, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: @tladuke I see the problem. You have the smaller (and obsolescent) 3-1/2" octagon box.  You'll need an adapter box to get you to the modern/standard 4" octagon box, or just to a 4" square box if you can find that. Edited.

Comment: Thank you. Google is also useless for this it seems. I don't think the box itself is grounded though.

Comment: @tladuke well, ground can always be retrofit, one way or the other. They liberalized the rules for doing that in 2014.