# Best solution for outdoor outlet with permanent connection?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, receptacle, outdoor

I have a circular junction box on my deck (outside) where I can presumably attach an outlet, and it is connected to a switch. I have string lights I'd like to permanently connect to to this outlet (they plug in normally).

What is the best weather-proof solution so that I can keep the lights plugged in, but have the outlet protected from the elements, and use the switch to turn them on and off?

Comment: A standard in-use wet location outlet cover should do. They all have interior capacity for plugged cords nowdays. Odd that your box is round, though. Was it intended as a light?

Comment: Yes it was... but I want the new "light" to be the string lights

Comment: My first inclination is to use a weathertight cover with a Cord Grip Bushing, but anything besides a receptacle and in-use cover would likely run into UL (CSA,ETL,MET) Listing issues for the light string.

Comment: An outside outlet will need to be GFCI protected.

Comment: [What is the difference between a weather resistant GFCI and a standard GFCI?](http://wiringdevicesupport.eaton.com/GFCI/70709712/What-is-the-difference-between-a-weather-resistant-GFCI-and-a-standard-GFCI.htm) It likely also includes a conformal coating over the internal circuitry to protect them from condensation.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease - "a weathertight cover with a Cord Grip Bushing", +1. UL; w/e: just can't sell it. Is there code that says you can't hardwire an exterior string light? Same as a pendant, no? Basically [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91916/patio-light-fixture-to-electrical-socket) but weathertight and a cord bushing instead of a box-to-box.

Comment: @Mazura, yes. The code says to follow manufacturers instructions... once you cut the cord cap off and hard-wire a set of string lights... goodbye UL Listing and goodbye code compliance. Not that it wouldn't work though; I would do it...

Comment: Note that NEC 590.3(B) sets a 90-day limit on holiday lighting type products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a weatherproof 4/O to single-gang plate with in-use cover:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this: Add a blank cover on that box and use a close nipple to add another rectangular outlet box below it. Then in that rectanglar box, install a GFCI receptacle (unless this is fed from a GFCI circuit breaker already). Then you can get what's called an "in-use" weatherproof cover for the rectangular box. In-use covers have a gasketed flip-up cover that also provides a small flanged opening at the bottom for a cord to come out.

[image]

The reason for the rectangular box is because they don't make in-use WP covers for round boxes, because round outdoor boxes are not made to house receptacles.